# How do i connect my backend(nodejs) to my react app all runing on gitpod

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package.json, http-proxy, gitpod

i want to connect my backend to the react app using the proxy in package.json but i got an error showing up at the front page of the react app "invalid host header"

i tried these "proxy": "http://localhost:5000", and then i tried these "proxy": "https://5000-kcpele-shopclone1-7vpnj3r84gc.ws-eu38.gitpod.io/"
I was expecting it to connect so i could use axios to fetch the data from the backend api like these axios.get("/api/products")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check out the last(recent) comments in these two below issues for solutions:

- https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/628
- https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/26